# hiding elements when out of focus jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a set of compliance links for keyboard users. The objective is to only display the second skip link once the destination of the first link has taken focus (the user has clicked "skip-link and it has reached the href destination). The following code is intended to handle this, but does not hide the second skip when the first does not have focus

**jQuery:**

```
if ($('#anchor').focus) {
    $('#skip-link-tabs').show();
}else {
    $('#skip-link-tabs').hide();
}
```

**html:**

```
<span id="anchor" tabindex="0" style="margin-right:10px">Main</span>

<a id="skip-link-tabs" href="#toTabs" style="margin-right:10px; color:black;">To tabs</a>

<span id="toTabs" tabindex="0" style="margin-right:10px">Tabs</span>
```

This code has been minimized to only show the relevant parts, since this is a rather large page.

Comment: It's `focus()`, not `focus`

Comment: @Ionut Hello again. checking resolution now

Comment: I might have to be a function, e.g. `$('#anchor').focus(function() { ... });`

Comment: @putvande That was the issue, if you want to set this as the answer, I would like to upvote and select as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focus` isn't a property of your jQuery object. If it was, it would still not work as the code doesn't get updated by an event. So what you need to do is check for the `focus` event, e.g.:

```
$('#anchor').focus(function() { 
  $('#skip-link-tabs').show();
});
```

[focus event](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

And you can hide it by doing

```
$('#anchor').focusout(function() { 
  $('#skip-link-tabs').hide();
});
```

[focusout event](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Checkout the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/putvande/nnjrx8c2/)

Perhaps even better would be:

```
var skipLinkTabs = $('#skip-link-tabs');
$('#anchor').focus(function() { 
  skipLinkTabs.show();
}).focusout(function() { 
  skipLinkTabs.hide();
});
```

(Chaining + caching the jQuery element)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for `focus()` instead of `focus`

Comment: I just noticed this was already discussed in the comments, my apologies

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses the focus to show the links and blur to hide when losing focus.

```js
$('#anchor').focus(function(e){
  $('#skip-link-tabs').show();
});
$( "#anchor" ).blur(function() {
  $('#skip-link-tabs').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="anchor" tabindex="0" style="margin-right:10px">Main</span>

        <a id="skip-link-tabs" href="#toTabs" style="margin-right:10px; color:black;">To tabs</a>

     <span id="toTabs" tabindex="0" style="margin-right:10px">Tabs</span>
```